# Add to cart form not adding items to cart

Tags: shopify, liquid, cart

I'm trying to create buttons that add specific quantities of a product to the cart, so I modified the form that is automatically generated by the product page in Shopify, but it seems my code won't add any products from any of my 3 buttons to the cart page. I created 3 different IDs because each button posts the same product but a different quantity of that product. It also has a different description otherwise I would just leave it as 1 ID to keep it simple.

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm">
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
          {% if variant.available %}
            <option value="{{ variant.id }}">
              {{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}
            </option>
          {% else %}
            <option disabled="disabled">
              {{ variant.title }} - sold out
            </option>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {{ current_variant.price | money }}
      <input type="hidden" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1">
      <input type="submit" class="two-cans" name="id" quantity="1" id="6556104458433" value="Get 2 Cans"/>
      <input type="submit" class="four-cans" name="id" quantity="2" id="6556136014017" value="Get 4 Cans"/>
      <input type="submit" class="six-cans" name="id" quantity="3" id="6556139389121" value="Get 6 Cans"/>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `id` attribute on a submit button will not do what you expect it to do, as it has nothing to do with the actual Shopify id of a product or a variant.
The `quantity` attribute does not do anything by itself, so that will not work either.

A typical add to cart form will look something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/cart/add">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
  <input min="1" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" />
</form>
```

For your specific use case, a good approach would be using JS instead of liquid. You can use Shopify's REST Api, start by replacing the submit inputs with simple buttons and moving them outside of the form:

```
<button class="custom-submit-button two-cans" name="id" quantity="2" id="6556104458433">Get 2 Cans</button>
<button class="custom-submit-button four-cans" name="id" quantity="4" id="6556136014017">Get 4 Cans</button>
<button class="custom-submit-button six-cans" name="id" quantity="6" id="6556139389121">Get 6 Cans</button>
```

Then adding a bit of jQuery to handle the requests:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function addItemToCart(variant_id, qty) {
    var data = {
      "id": variant_id,
      "quantity": qty
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/cart/add.js',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() { 
        location.reload();
      }
    });
}
  
$('.custom-submit-button').click(function(){    
    addItemToCart($(this).attr("id"), $(this).attr("quantity"));
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply cMarius. I copied the code you wrote and applied the JQuery to my theme file and made the changes to my buttons on my index file, but should I replace the existing product form in my product file? Or should I paste the form in my index file just above my buttons as well? I heard that might bring up some problems from a tutorial video I watched earlier. Something about a bad interaction between product.variant and the index file... not sure if I'm explaining it very well...

Comment: Can you link the tutorial? Generally you should include these buttons only on the pages you want them to show up, for example, if you want them on the product page, you can include them in `product.liquid`, or if you want them on the homepage, then there's `index.liquid`, or `cart.liquid` for the cart page. I assume the form you are reffering to is for adding regular items to the cart and is located in the `product.liquid` file, so you can probably safely leave that in there.